# php from a string get or print specialchar, number, alphabetic seprate seprate in php

Tags: php

I have a string like:

```
$str = "hello@$how%&*!are345You^_THere56";
```

I want that alphabet stores in one variable like:

```
hello,how,are,you,THere
```

Number should be stored in one variable like:

```
3,4,5,5,6
```

special characters separately:

```
@$%&*!^_
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, the best choice for this is to use [`preg_split`](https://php.net/preg_split):

```
<?php
$str = 'hello@$how%&*!are345You^_THere56';
$words = array_filter(preg_split('/[^a-zA-Z]/', $str));
$numbers = str_split(join('', preg_split('/[^0-9]/', $str)));
$specials = str_split(join('', preg_split('/[a-zA-Z0-9]/', $str)))

print_r($words);
print_r($numbers);
print_r($specials);
```

By negating character classes we can filter the results how we want. The `str_split` an `join` calls are to split on character basis rather than on group basis.

Results:

```
Array
(
    [0] => hello
    [2] => how
    [6] => are
    [9] => You
    [11] => THere
)
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 5
    [3] => 5
    [4] => 6
)
Array
(
    [0] => @
    [1] => $
    [2] => %
    [3] => &
    [4] => *
    [5] => !
    [6] => ^
    [7] => _
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check for regex match.

```
$str = "hello@$how%&*!are345You^_THere56";

for($i=0; $i<strlen($str ); $i++) 
     if($str[$i] == "^[0-9]*$") {
           //store numbers
      }
     else-if($str[$i] == "^[a-zA-Z]*$") {
     // store characters
       }
    else {
       //store special characters
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$strs = '';
$num = '';
$sc = '';

$str = 'hello@$how%&*!are345You^_THere56';
$a = str_split($str);
$prev = '';
foreach($a as $v){
    switch($v){
        case is_numeric($v):
            $num .= $v;
            break;
        case preg_match('/[a-zA-Z]/',$v):
                $sc .= $v;
            break;
        default:
            $strs .= $v;
            break;
    }
    $prev = $v;
}

echo "<p>";
echo "<p>Strings: ".$strs."</p>";
echo "<p>Numbers: ".$num."</p>";
echo "<p>Special Characters: ".$sc."</p>";
```

Comment: @PrashantRai You should vote up the answer if it helped you.